# Are rotation matrices faithful representations of the rotation group?

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory, rotations

I would like to use rotation matrices as representations of the rotation group. I would like to know if these representations are faithful, i.e. isomorphic to the rotational group elements.

I read that "Only the j = 1 representation is isomorphic to the rotation group itself."

Can someone explain to my why this is the case?

Comment: What is $j$ here, the dimension of the space in which rotations are done? Are they Euclidean spaces?

Comment: j=1 means that the eigenvalue of J^2 is j(j+1), where J^2=J_x^2+J_y^2+J_z^2, where J_i is the generator of rotation about the i-axis.

Comment: Yes, since j=1.

Comment: You seem to be using an unorthodox definition of "faithful". Conventionally, a faithful representation is defined to be an injective one (see e.g. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faithful_representation)).